# Origin of the "@attributes" element in JSON generated from XML

Tags: javascript, xml, json

How and/or in which conventions are XML attributes put in an object named "@attributes" when converting XML to JSON? This style is used in [this generic XML parser](http://davidwalsh.name/convert-xml-json):

```
obj["@attributes"] = {};
for (var j = 0; j < xml.attributes.length; j++) {
  var attribute = xml.attributes.item(j);
  obj["@attributes"][attribute.nodeName] = attribute.nodeValue;
}
```

..to create JSON like this:

```
...
elem_array = [
  {
    "@attributes": {
      an-attribute: "",
      another-one: "mr.text"
    }
  }
]
...
```

I'm not looking for answers about element-centric vs. attribute-centric XML design, unless those things are more closely related to my question than I thought of course. ;)

Where did the @attributes notation come from and are there reasons to use it over using your own notation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is likely evolved from the XPATH @attribute syntax

http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xpathattribute.php

Using the @ makes it recognisable to people used to XPATH

Example: [XPath : Get nodes where child node contains an attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457638/xpath-get-nodes-where-child-node-contains-an-attribute)

Comment: Then using names like "@another-one":"mr.text" would make the attributes recognizable.
Why put all attributes in one @attributes element?

Comment: Because there are more than one attribute on the one xml tag?

Comment: I agree it's a clean way to group multiple attributes, but that tells us nothing about the origin of this style or if there's a reason we should choose this convention over any other one.

Comment: It seems to have been chosen for us if we use the parser in question :) - Not sure what you want to get out of this question...

Comment: Good point! Maybe I wrongly assumed that it was a convention in the first place. Probably because of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957371/is-use-of-attributes-in-json-non-standard-or-standard)this SO question.

Comment: Right. I would not worry about it since any XPATH person would not have an issue with bla["@attributes"]